# Why is my tar file bigger than its contents?

Tags: linux, tar, data-recovery

I have a tar file that I have recreated from two files - xaa, xab (the results of using the split command). The tar file is the size I expect it to be but when I extract it the folder I get is a fraction of the size of the tar file. See the terminal output below for the sequence of my commands. Unfortunately I don't have the orignal tar file or folder - so this is my only chance to recover this data. When I open the archive in the 'File Roller' I see the same folders as I do on the command line after extraction and these are only a subset of the files I'd expect to see. Can anyone suggest why this might be?

```
~> cat xa* > archive
~> file archive
archive: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
~> ls -la archive
-rw-r--r-- 1 hugo users 24471439360 Jun  1 18:50 archive
~> tar xf archive
~> cd repos
~/repos> du --max-depth 0 -h
83M .
~/repos> cd ../
~> tar cf newarchive repos
~> ls -la newarchive
-rw-r--r-- 1 hugo users 53288960 Jun  1 19:57 newarchive
```

Comment: What about `tar tvvf archive | awk '{s+=$3}; END{print s}'`? Are you sure everything is in `repos`. No dot file or dot dir like `.git` or `.svn`? `tar tvvf archive | less` to see where the space is.

Comment: There are no other folders other than repos. The awk command gives:
    `~> tar tvvf archive | awk '{s+=$3}; END{print s}'
    29084601`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tar file is extracted until it finds the marker indicating the end of tar file: *Physically, an archive consists of a series of file entries terminated by an end-of-archive entry, which consists of two 512 blocks of zero bytes* from the tar file format description [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html).

So your archive file probably has material after the marker that does not get extracted.

Comment: Aha, yes it looks like that tar was seeing an end-of-archive that wasn't the real end-of-archive. Using the i flag to tar seems to be the solution - it ignores end-of-archive delimiters and processes the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the disk to which you are extracting doesn't have enough free space for all of the files and directories in the tar archive.  Check with `df -k .` in the directory in which you extracted the files.

Sometimes if you tar up files with "holes" in them, you will get a tar archive file much bigger than the original file(s). Also, a tar archive file carries metadata, file name, permissions, ownership, etc, as well as the file(s) data. So a tar archive is invariably at least a little bigger than the original files.

Comment: If the disk were full, you would get an error saying so.