# Why is my tar file bigger than the directory backed up

Tags: tar, disk-usage

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77899/why-is-my-tar-file-bigger-than-its-contents) did not help me (despite having the same title). So I post this even though this is a duplicate question.

As far as I can tell, the total in `du -k` includes all the subdirectories and indicates I have 77 megabytes of data

```
/raid/fpuData/oldOutput>du -ks
77063332        .
/raid/fpuData/oldOutput>tar -cvzf ../oldOutput.tar.zip *
```

The backup is sill running, but already the file is considerably bigger than 77 megabytes

```
/raid/fpuData>ls oldOutput.tar.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nobody 14470610944 Jul  1 22:18 oldOutput.tar.zip
```

The files I'm backing up are all huge text files filled with numbers, like a huge comma delimited spreadsheet). Something like this

```
0.3454915028125262743685653,0.5590169943749474512628694,...
0.221761776923297210251107,0.3588180924674668759166707,...
-0.06101864995889930837202897,-0.09873024958113109372792593,...
-0.3001958820500086333460388,-0.4857271404396689140625654,...
...
```

Why is the `tar` file bigger than the directory? It should be compressed because I'm using the data with the `z` option. What's the point of `tar`ring it, then?

Comment: You may already realize this, but the correct extension is `.tar.gz`. Read [this](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-zip-and-gzip/).

Comment: As a theoretical note: it's easy to show that, given *any* data-compressing algorithm, there exists texts such that the resulting  output is at least as long as the original text. Otherwise, given a string of *any* length, X you could compress it to Y, a string of length *strictly* less than the length of X. This means that *any* file could be compressed, by multiple applications of the algorithm, to the empty file, which is absurd since data-compressing algorithms must be bijective/reversible. Hence it's not strange for archives to have bigger size than the original data.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your compressed tar file is smaller than its contents.

`ls` prints file sizes in bytes by default.
`du -k` prints file sizes in kilobytes.

[image: 0610944B ≈ 14131456KB < 77063332KB]

To make `ls` print file sizes in kilobytes, use the `-k` flag.

Comment: I guess I could complain about Linux not using a "k" unit symbol or be happy that I have an answer - either way you are correct. The final `tar`d file size, using `ls -k oldOutput.tar.zip` is 32703224 - less than half the original.

Comment: You can use the `-h` flag with both `du` and `ls` to get human-readable sizes. If you would like that to be your default, add a couple of aliases to your interactive shell config (`.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, etc): `alias du='du -h'` and `alias ls='ls -h'`.

Answer (score 2):

Remember if you compress primary BINARY data (i.e. *.gz, *.zip)  it is possible/probable that you will get an output file that is FAR LARGER than the original aggregation.  So I'd lose the -z switch on the tar you are trying.

Comment: The OP is compressing _text_, not binary data. The text happens to be numbers but it is still text: "The files I'm backing up are all huge text files filled with numbers".

Comment: See the command: `tar -cvzf ../oldOutput.tar.zip *`, it is compressing via `tar -z` an already zipped and compressed file which at that point IS binary data!

Comment: mdpc: Please clarify. What do you mean I am compressing already zipped files. It seems to me that @terdon's original comment is correct.

Comment: @Jeff you're quite right, I misread the command when I agreed with @mdpc. Your command is correctly creating  `oldOutput.tar.zip` from (presumably) uncompressed files.

Comment: `tar -cvf` created a much larger file than `tar -cvzf` - but it ran faster.

Answer (score 2):

Text files don't compress better just because they labeled with a "txt" extension.  Text files often compress better because there tends to be a lot of extra "white space" and duplicated letter usage.

I postulate that your CSV file has little to no "white space" to clean up and actually emulates a binary or graphics image file instead.

Comment: There is no white space at all in my CSV files, unless new lines are considered whitespace - probably not - in which case each file has exactly 10,000 white space characters.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you backup sparse files without the tar option `--sparse`?

You can easily find out by extracting the archive after it has been finished and comparing the source directory with the extracted directory.