# Why is tar archive so much bigger than text file, 10240 bytes?

Tags: tar

I've checked these two questions ([question one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81424/why-is-my-tar-file-bigger-than-the-directory-backed-up), [question two](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77899/why-is-my-tar-file-bigger-than-its-contents)), but they were not helpful for me to understand. I have a file `file.txt` with 40 lines of `Hello World!` string. `ls -l` shows that its size is 520 bytes. Now I archive this file with `tar -cvf file.tar file.txt` and when I do `ls -l` again I see that `file.tar` is 10240 bytes. Why?

I've read some manuals and have understood that archiving and compressing are different things. But can someone please explain how it is working?

Comment: Also worth noting: `tar` by itself does not do any compression. So the output tar file will always be larger than the input file. That's why tar files are usually ran through a compressor like `gz`.

Comment: Have you examined the `.tar` file to check the contents?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo “That's why tar files are usually ran through a compressor like `gz`” – well, they often are, but I wouldn't say “usually”. It certainly doesn't always make sense, in particular not when the archive contains e.g. compressed video files where another layer of general-purpose compression is completely useless but may take significant computation resources.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I've rarely seen a tar file that wasn't then compressed with some algorithm. I would certainly say usually and, although it would be impossible to prove, would venture to say that >90% of all tar files are also compressed.

Comment: @Ben that seems likely for publicly-visible tarballs; however given the volume of data stored on tape in various organisations around the world, and the many instances where such tarballs aren’t compressed (*e.g.* because the tape drives do their own compression), it also seems likely that the proportion of compressed tarballs is far less than 90% when considering all tarballs.

Comment: Of course, the file also occupies more than 520 bytes in the file system. Most likely not as much as 10K, but still more than the size indicated by `ls` or `dir`.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`tar` archives have a minimum size of 10240 bytes by default; see [the GNU `tar` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Blocking-Factor.html) for details (but this is not GNU-specific).

With GNU `tar`, you can reduce this by specifying either a different block size, or different block factor, or both:

```
tar -cv -b 1 -f file.tar file.txt
```

The result will still be bigger than `file.txt`, because `file.tar` stores metadata about `file.txt` in addition to `file.txt` itself. In most cases you’ll see one block for the file’s metadata (name, size, timestamps, ownership, permissions), then the file content, then two blocks for the end-of-archive entry, so the smallest archive containing a non-zero-length file is four blocks in size (2,048 bytes with a 512-byte block).

Comment: Note libarchive's `bsdtar` (which also supports `-b`) uses 512 byte blocks by default when the output goes to a regular file or is compressed with compression options passed to `bsdtar` (the compressed file itself will end up being *padded* to a 10k block though if it doesn't go to a regular file).

Comment: Explanation for that odd ball default: Tar was once commonly used with actual tapes, which often had such odd block sizes

Comment: @rackandboneman I still use tapes, but not with `tar`!

Comment: @rackandboneman: `tar` literally stands for Tape ARchive, so yeah it's no surprise the format was designed around writing directly to tapes.

Comment: @rackandboneman: These sizes are not odd, they are *very* even: Most of them are powers of 2 ;) 2^9 = 512, 2^20=2048 etc...

Answer (score 29):

`tar` needs to do three things apart from simply storing files:

1. Store metadata (name of the file, mode, owner, group, dates...)
2. Mark the end of the file.
3. Mark the end of the archive.

`tar` means "tape archive". For tapes it is important to decide, where is the file end, and the device needs to know it even when searching (the tape moves faster). So tar for the tape convenience adds some zeroes at the end of every file and another set of seroes at the end of the archive. The second question you pointed at does explain this.

You can see what is in the archive using `hexdump -C archive.tar |less`.